# determine independence of samples for a hypothesis test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binary-data

I have two binary variables A and B. In my case, A is the presence of the flu, and B is the presence of another pathogen. I want to answer the following question: **Are the percentages P(A|B) and P(A|~B) significantly different?**

To answer my question above, I would like to use a [two proportions z test](http://stattrek.com/hypothesis-test/difference-in-proportions.aspx). According to the link cited, I can use this test only if certain conditions are met. One of these conditions is that "the samples are independent". Are my samples disqualified? I think the answer is yes,  because the sets (A|B) and (A|~B) cover all possible sets of A, and as such removing one A from a set requires that it be in the other set. However, I don't know if this kind of reasoning is what independence means here.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an issue since each subject appears just once, no matter if B is 0 or 1. (Assuming of course there is no other source of dependence.)

More typical here would be to run Fisher's exact test instead of a two-sample binomial test, but that is up to you. Remember that these tests assume a random sample from a large population.

Comment: Can you be more specific please? What's the connection between how often a subject appears, and independence?